# Model-View-Controller: who notifies the View

Tags: model-view-controller

The user-input is received by the Controller. The Controller manipulates/edits the Model.
The View can query the Model in order to obtain the new state for diplaying. The point I do not get is who actually notifies the View of changes? Because in the schematic overview, It seems that the Controller sends modification messages and that the Model also notifies the View of changes.

Even in the example, both notify the View. If the controller sends for example the position of the needle, why must the Model still notify the View?

[The figures are from the slides of our prof, so they are correct anyway]

[image: MVC]

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was becoming a bit confusing, so I googled to see what some leading [authorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) have to say, because Wikipedia and the first hits are not as good as they seemed to be.

- **Model**. The Model manages the behavior and data of the application domain, responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the View), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the Controller).
- **View**. The View manages the display of information.
- **Controller**. The Controller interprets the mouse and keyboard inputs from the user, *informing* the Model and/or the View to change as appropriate.

So it seems that the Controller notifies the View.

But it is important to note that both the View and the Controller depend on the Model. However, **the Model depends on neither the View nor the Controller**. This is one of the key benefits of the separation. This separation allows the model to be built and tested independent of the visual presentation.

[image: MVC]

And of course the Controller cannot be the only one who changes the Model. For that reason there are indeed some variations:

The **passive** model is employed when one Controller manipulates the Model exclusively. The controller modifies the Model and then informs the View that the Model has changed and should be refreshed. The Model in this scenario is completely independent of the View and the Controller, which means that there is no means for the Model to report changes in its state.

The **active** model is used when the Model changes state without the controller's involvement. This can happen when other sources are changing the data and the changes must be reflected in the Views. Because only the Model detects changes to its internal state when they occur, the Model must notify the views to refresh the display.
-> Explains the case.

Answer (score 2):

Model does not have to necessarily notify the View - in that case you get a passive implementation of MVC, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

The model can for example compute something in the background, e.g. it could be computing positions of particles in a particle system and here and there it could notify the view to update itself - i.e. the push model which is often more efficient than polling the model from the View.

For example before WebSockets and Comet, it would be always the Web view notifying the Controller which would poll a Model and render a new View. With WebSockets or Comet you can have the Controller notifying the View.

In any case, there are myriads of spins on implementing MVC, it's not set in stone and of course you can adapt it to your use case.

Comment: So it's rather a choice of letting the View polling the model, the Model notifying the View directly, or the Controller updating the Model -> Model notifying the Controller -> Controller notifying the view, or the Controller updating the Model -> Controller polling the Model's state -> Controller notifying the view?

Comment: Yes, there is a range of choices. For example before WebSockets and Comet, it would be always the Web view notifying the Controller which would poll a Model and render a new View. With WebSockets or Comet you can have the Controller notifying the View. That said, your professor may have a stricter view on the matter.

Comment: @Matthias , that is not MVC. What you describe could maybe referred to as MVP.

Comment: @tereško all four choices?